# Wt FastCGI Incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server

Tags: c++, fastcgi, archlinux, wt

I'm struggling to set up Apache to work with a Wt app on FastCGI.

I'm using arch linux and Apache 2.4.7.
gcc 4.9.0 20140604

The [hello world](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/src/hello) example, which is the simplest example there is, after compilation gives me this error:

```
[Thu Sep 11 22:46:01.208926 2014] [fastcgi:error] [pid 27628] (101)Network is unreachable: [client 127.0.0.1:52788] FastCGI: failed to connect to server "/xxx/hello/hello.wt": connect() failed, referer: http://local.hello/
[Thu Sep 11 22:46:01.208992 2014] [fastcgi:error] [pid 27628] [client 127.0.0.1:52788] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/xxx/hello/hello.wt", referer: http://local.hello/
```

**Here's what I do**:

Compile with:

```
$ g++ -o hello.wt hello.cpp -lwtfcgi -lwt
```

My vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@xxx.com
    DocumentRoot "/xxx/hello"
    ServerName local.hello
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/local.hello-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/local.hello-access_log" common
    <Directory /xxx/hello/>
        Options All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    FastCgiExternalServer /xxx/hello/hello.wt -host 127.0.0.0:9090
</VirtualHost>
```

and my fastcgi.conf that's being included from httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule fastcgi_module>
  AddHandler fastcgi-script .wt
#  FastCgiIpcDir /tmp/fcgi_ipc/  # DOESN'T COMPILE WITH THIS UNCOMMENTED
  FastCgiConfig -idle-timeout 100 -maxClassProcesses 1 -initial-env WT_APP_ROOT=/tmp
</IfModule>
```

If I compile it with:

```
$ g++ -o hello.wt hello.cpp -lwthttp -lwt
```

and run it with:

```
$ ./hello --docroot . --http-address 0.0.0.0 --http-port 9090
```

everything works fine, so I'm thinking it's something with my apache/fastcgi setup.

Every hint is mostly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error but I don't remember exactly what it was, and whether I had different issues, but perhaps your main problem is that you haven't created the `/var/run/wt` folder used by Wt to manage sessions when it uses the fastcgi connector.

The thing is that, at least in Ubuntu, `/var/run` uses a tmpfs filesystem, which is a filesystem mounted directly in RAM and thus, deleted at each reboot. So, you need to ensure that folder exists and with proper permissions, each time you reboot the server.

Why `/var/run/wt` and not another folder? That depends on the folder you have set in your `wt_config.xml` file. In Ubuntu 14.04, that file exists under `/etc/wt/wt_config.xml`; XML tag `<run-directory>`, under the `<connector-fcgi>` section. You can change that directive to point to another persistent folder if you want.

What I made however is creating a `init` job for creating the `/var/run/wt/` folder at startup, creating the file `/etc/init/witty.conf` with the following contents (a `upstart` script):

```
#
# This task is run on startup to create the Witty's run folder
# (currently /var/run/wt) with suitable permissions.

description     "set witty's run folder (/var/run/wt)"

start on startup

task
exec /usr/local/bin/witty_mkrunfolder
```

And my `witty_mkrunfolder` executable is:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /var/run/wt
chown -R root:www-data /var/run/wt
chmod -R 770 /var/run/wt
```

Extra: `witty_mkrunfolder` permissions:

```
$ chown root:root witty_mkrunfolder
$ chmod 750 witty_mkrunfolder
```